# Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS apt-get error message

Tags: 16.04, server

When I enter `sudo apt-get update` I see these errors:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                         
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner Sources [2,316 B]     
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release  
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial Release                                                                
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages 
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Fetched 309 kB in 5s (55.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/martinx/ig/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

*sourses.list* file content

```
#

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)$

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted unive$
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted$

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: The error means it can't find two of the software sources.

Comment: Please show the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to Xenial 16.04?

Comment: @MarkYisri No, I installed 16.04 at the first time, I updated the post too

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the whole file? I see no mention of those repositories in it. If so, then please re-run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @MarkYisri Yes, its the whole file.
same error message with `sudo apt update`

Comment: @muru the server version doesn't include GUI

Comment: OK. So? Do all answers in that post use GUIs?

Comment: @muru no, sorry I'll check the answers again